# How to match enum with parameter without destructing in Rust?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, move-semantics

I have enum with variants with value:

```rust
enum Foobar<T, G> {
    Foo,
    Bar(T),
    Baz(G),
}
```

I have a piece of code where I need to match enum value, but I don't want to destruct it.

```
fn foobar<T, G, F1, F2>(value: Foobar<T, G>, f1: F1, f2: F2) -> bool
where
    F1: Fn(T) -> bool,
    F2: Fn(G),
{
    let res = match value {
        Foobar::Foo => true,
        Foobar::Bar(v) => f1(v),
        Foobar::Baz => false,
    };
    if let Foobar::Baz(v2) = value {
        f2(v2);
    }
    res
}
```

It won't compile because `expected unit struct, unit variant or constant, found tuple variant Foobar::Baz`

I don't want to cange it to `Foobar::Baz(_)` because it will force Copy trait on `G`, and I don't want it.

My example is a bit artificial, but let's assume I need to keep separate call to `f2`.

Is there a way to match an enum variant without destructing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

But it wouldn't help anyway. The problem is that `value` is not available after the `match` because you (might have) moved data from it into `f1`.

You can fix it by reorganising the code a little, so that you only look at `Baz` when the value from `Bar` has not been moved:

```
fn foobar<T, G, F1, F2>(value: Foobar<T, G>, f1: F1, f2: F2) -> bool
where
    F1: Fn(T) -> bool,
    F2: Fn(G),
{
    let res = match value {
        Foobar::Foo => true,
        Foobar::Bar(v) => f1(v),
        Foobar::Baz(v2) => {
            f2(v2);
            false
        },
    };
    res
}
```